# Swift override protocol methods in sub classes

Tags: ios, swift, overriding, protocols, ios-extensions

I've a base class that implements an extension that conforms to a protocol as below:

```
protocol OptionsDelegate {
    func handleSortAndFilter(opt: Options)
}

extension BaseViewController: OptionsDelegate {
    func handleSortAndFilter(opt: Options) {
        print("Base class implementation")
    }
}
```

I've a subclass "InspirationsViewController" that inherits from BaseViewController. And I'm overriding protocol method in the extension as below:

```
extension InspirationsViewController {
    override func handleSortAndFilter(opt: Options) {
        print("Inside inspirations")
    }
}
```

I'm getting error when I override "handleSortAndFilter" function in subclass extension: ***"Declerations in extensions cannot override yet"***

But I'm not seeing similar problem when I implemented UITableView datasource and delegate methods.

How to avoid this error?

Comment: `InspirationsViewController` is not a subclass, its an extension. I think you defined it wrong. It should be a class `InspirationsViewController: BaseViewController`

Comment: @HossamGhareeb he already said `InspirationsViewController` is subclass of `BaseViewController` , this is extension for it. This problem is probably haven't got implemented in Swift, you should do override from main class, extension is for adding more function

Comment: In extension we can not override methods of the super class.

Comment: Please post the class definitions also. The code compiles fine here adding `class BaseViewController: UIViewController{}` and `class InspirationsViewController: BaseViewController {}`.

Comment: @shallowThought, Class declaration that you mentioned is correct.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use protocol extension with where clause. It works.
But I would **not** recommend you to have such things in your codebase.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

}

extension OptionsDelegate where Self: BaseViewController {
  func handleSortAndFilter(opt: Options) {
    print("Base class implementation")
  }
}

extension BaseViewController: OptionsDelegate {

}

class InsipartionsViewController: BaseViewController {

}

extension OptionsDelegate where Self: InsipartionsViewController {
  func handleSortAndFilter(opt: Options) {
    print("Inspirations class implementation")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Can you please provide some explanation to understand the implementation?

Comment: Its compiling perfect. But its never calling override function implemented in "InsipartionsViewController".

Comment: https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E29-protocols-class-hierarchies checkout this video about protocols and class hierarchies in swift.

Comment: Hmmm. I tried this, but I'm not able to call the protocol method. E.g., let x = InsipartionsViewController(); x.handleSortAndFilter(opt:...) doesn't compile for me.

Comment: Ah. Got it now, I had to make UIViewController abide by the protocol.

Comment: This is great! Unfortunately the methods cannot access internal properties (private) to the class. Ex: it can't access private vars in InspirationsViewController

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know you can't override methods in extensions. Extensions can only do the following:
“Extensions in Swift can:

- Add computed instance properties and computed type properties
- Define instance methods and type methods
- Provide new initializers
- Define subscripts
- Define and use new nested types
- Make an existing type conform to a protocol”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.0.1).”