# JSQMessages cannot override method Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

For some reason I cannot override methods in Swift 3 using JSQMessages.

These methods are defined in the `JSQMessagesCollectionViewDataSource`

`public func senderDisplayName() -> String!`

`public func senderId() -> String!`

When I subclass JSQMessagesViewController I try to implement the methods as such:

```
override func senderId() -> String {
    return User.Wozniak.rawValue
}

override public func senderDisplayName() -> String! {
    return getName(.Wozniak)
}
```

However I get the error that it does not override any method from its super class. When I remove override it says it conflicts with an Obj-C selector.

Comment: Just curious, but what happens if you add the "@objc" attribute to the functions?

Comment: Similar issues [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41344287/3687801) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25788782/3687801). Take a look if any of them solves your problem.

Comment: @nayem hii have u worked with JSQMessagesViewController i need help from u

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented this functionality in swift 3 with following Properties

```
self.senderId = "my ID"
self.senderDisplayName = "Wozniac"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try this instead:

```
open override func senderId() -> String {
    ...
}
```

but I'm not sure if it will fix your issue completely.

According to *[SE-0117: Allow distinguishing between public access and public overridability](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0117-non-public-subclassable-by-default.md)*, which introduces the `open` keyword, the rules for imported Objective-C code are (emphasis mine):

> Objective-C classes and methods are always imported as **open**. This means that the synthesized header for an Objective-C class would pervasively replace **public** with **open** in its interface.

Of course, assuming `JSQMessages` is still implemented in pure Objective-C.